# Main Page notifications in Magento Index

Tags: magento-1.9

On [this page](http://rpsonline.com.sg/rpsweb/authors/?___store=default) We have more notification errors, how can I retrieve?

Comment: Please share - and describe - errors you're experiencing on your site in text form (and/or screenshots) within your question so future reader can find help in case they suffer a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Template path hints are enabled on your site. Follow the below steps to disable it.

1. Log into the Magento admin.
2. Go to **System -> Configuration** in the main menu
3. In the panel on the left under **Advanced**, choose **Developer**.
4. Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.
5. Under the **Debug** tab, there will be an option called **Template Path Hints**.
6. Set the option to "**No**" to disable the hints.
7. Flush Cache (System -> Cache Management).

Check the link to know more about Magento template path hints. http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/system/template-path-hints.html

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look to me like errors but instead you have path hints on, go to

```
Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront
```

and select "No". If this happens in the admin area as well do

```
Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled
Template Path Hints for Admin > No
```

Flush cache and let me know if i've helped you or not :)